# Attach parameter(s) with $http Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, token

I have $http request in Angularjs project.

```
   $http.get('http://api.domain.com/index?abc=123')
                    .success(function (data) {
                       console.log('Success!');
                    })
                    .error(function (data) { 
                       console.log('False');
                    });
```

Now, i want add **token** to each $http request, like

```
$http.get('http://api.domain.com/index?abc=123&token=456')...
```

I know a way to send token via header:

```
$http.defaults.headers.common['X-AUTH-TOKEN'] = token;
```

But i want use it as parameter, can i?

Regards!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `params` option in config of `$http`

```
var myHttpConfig = {
  params: {
    abc: 123,
    token: 456
  }
}

$http.get( url, myHttpCongig).then(function...
```

If you want an app wide approach to send the same params use $http interceptors

Note that `success` and `error` are now deprecated per the [$http docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)